# how to maximize number of connections?

Tags: java, tomcat

I use server Tomcat + HttpServlet + hibernate. I test the server performance, for this, I created an application that simulates the operation 500 clients, each client with a periodicity repeats HTTP requests to the server. 
**When the number of clients reaches 350 I start getting errors**

`org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.0.122:8080 refused`

tell me please, how can I solve this problem? - increase the the number of clients to 5,000

Comment: http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.be/2009/01/tomcat-maxthreads-configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for the good article